# Как реализовать функцию с условием, если условий стало больше?

Tags: jquery, select, javascript

Есть плагин на чистом `js`, который реализует кастомный `selectbox`. Я написал код на `jquery`, который делает исключение для плагина, чтобы он не стилизовал определенные селектбоксы.

Сам вызов плагина выглядит так:

```
   CustomUI().selectbox({
     el: document.getElementById('selectboxID')
   });
```

А вот полный код обертки на `jquery`:

```
(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.custom_selectbox = {
    attach: function (context) {

        function useFakeSelect(){
            if((arguments[0] == 'edit-web-form') || ($('#' + arguments[0]).next('div').attr('id') == 'fake-select-box')){
                /* do nothing */
            }else{
                /* вставляю стилизованный через css фейковый selectbox */
                $('#' + arguments[0]).after('<div id=fake-select-box />');
            }
        }

        function CustomizeSelectboxes(){
           CustomUI().selectbox({
             el: document.getElementById(arguments[0])
           });
        }

        $('select').each(function(index){
            var ids = $(this).attr('id');
            /* вот здесь происходит фильтрация по id */
            /* нужно добавить еще два id и класс body */
            /* мне кажется лучше переделать всю функцию, но как? */
            if((ids == 'edit-web-form' || ids == 'edit-group-of-variables') && ($('body').hasClass('page-variables-add'))){
                useFakeSelect(ids);
            }else{
                CustomizeSelectboxes(ids);
            }
        });

        /* это костыль для фейкового selectbox */
        /* выдергиваю текст из настоящего и добавляю в фейк */
        $("#edit-group-of-variables").change(function(){
              var optionText = "";
              $("#edit-group-of-variables option:selected").each(function () {
                    optionText += $(this).text() + " ";
                  });
              $("#fake-select-box").text(optionText);
        });

    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не пробовали изменить селектор:

```
$('select').not('#edit-web-form,#edit-group-of-variables')
           .each(function(index){...
```

а проверку

```
$('body').hasClass('page-variables-add')
```

вообще вынесите ещё выше

- [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/)